# Nothing happened when tap blank space of the list item, why?

Tags: list, swiftui

I just want to do something when I tap everywhere of the list item.

It's ok when tap on the item's Text(), but when I tap blank space of the item, nothing happened, why?

```
struct ItemView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hello")
            Spacer()
            Text("world")
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) { index in
                ItemView().onTapGesture {
                    print("item \(index) taped")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-=-=-=
I do some experiments, they are so weird!!!
    print "hello" if tap the Text hello;
    print "world" if tap the blank space;
    print "item 0" tapped if tap the Text world;

```
struct ItemView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hello").onTapGesture {
                print("hello tapped")
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                print("world tapped")
            }) {
                Text("world")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) { index in
                ItemView().onTapGesture {
                    print("item \(index) taped")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add background modifier to your ItemView with opacity

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) { index in
                ItemView()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.001))
                    .onTapGesture {
                    print("item \(index) taped")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Mac3n, It works. But I just wonder why they are so weird in swiftui.

Comment: My opinion is in SwiftUI a Spacer is just that spacing and not a view that can interact with it. But yes it so weird

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`contentShape(_:eoFill:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/contentshape(_:eofill:)) modifier

Comment: Can you show how that would work in a solution to the Question?

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: My answer is complete

Comment: How is this a complete answer? I spent fifteen minutes trying to figure out how to use this before giving up. A complete answer would show you where to place the method call and what arguments to call it with, this has neither.

Comment: I linked to the Apple docs; I gave the method and the authoritative link to its use. To my mind that’s complete, but if it didn’t help you it didn’t help.

Comment: It (almost) works like this: .contentShape(Rectangle()). However, the far right end of the row still ends up triggering the default NavigationLink behavior (in my case, I was using this with a NavigationLink).